# When Jenkin publishes artifact, its include only single project dll file and it skipped other dll from bin folder

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins, cicd

Quick summary :

- We have .net web application( Name - DemoApplication)
- able to build in local (bin folder has multiple dll like ABC.dll,xyz.dll and DemoApplication.dll)
- successfully build in Jenkin as well through MSBuild
- After publishing the artifact it includes DemoApplication.dll and the rest are skipped.

How to include the rest dll i.e all bin folders in Artifact generation?

Comment: Welcome to SO  it is very hard to answer your question because we don't know how you build (via `Jenkinsfile`?), how you publish your artifacts (globbing pattern), etc. You should enrich your question with as much information as possible - always keep in mind that the people out there know nothing about your system

Comment: Thanks, @mu88 ; It's resolved now. Added .nuspec file in the project directory, where I've included the bin(output)path.